# Understanding Example Async call on javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I was "playing" around with async calls on javascript and I am trying to make the next example work, but can't:

```
// calls function f on next event loop
function callAsync(f, ...args) {
    setTimeout(() => f(...args), 0);
}

var f = (a, b, cb) => cb(null, a + b);

f2 = () => {
    a = 2;
    b = 3;

    setTimeout(() => 
    f(a, b, (err, res) => {
        if (!err) console.log(res);
    }), 0);

    callAsync(f, a, b, (err, res) => {
        if (!err) console.log(res);
    });

    a = 10;
    b = -10;
}

f2();
```

So, by running this, you get as a result:

```
0
5
```

Why callAsync does not work - that is my question!

Comment: It is working, it logs 5 because the values of the first to arguments in `...args` are `2` and `3`. It doesn't matter if you modify `a` and `b` after, that doesn't affect `...args`.

Comment: But, using the same logic, the code block above which is essentially the `callAsync`, should produce the same result (`5`), but it does not...

Comment: No, the code above uses `a` and `b` which have been changed to `10` and `-10`. The `callAsync` doesn't use `a` and `b` but uses copies of them that were passed into `callAsync`. JavaScript doesn't have call-by-reference.

Comment: @Paulpro So how can I use it async as I wanted from the beggining?

Comment: @JohnZobolas: How do you want it to work?  This is the basics of the language, and has little to do with asynchronous programming.  If you call a function with some values and then you overwrite those values, you don't suddenly change what had been passed to that function.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes, my mistake, I got it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might make it clear.  Here, approximately, are the steps taken:

```
        define callAsync
        define f
        define f2
        f2()
          a = 2
          b = 3
 +------- setTimeout(() => f(a, b, callbackFn1), 0)
 |        callAsync(f, 2, 3, callbackFn)
 | +------- setTimeout(() => f(2, 3, callbackFn2), 0)
 | |      a = 10
 | |      b = -10
 | |    end f2
 +----> f(10, -10, calllbackFn1)
   |      callbackFn1(null, 10 + -10)
   |        if (!err) console.log(res)
   |          console.log(0)                     //~> 0
   |    end f
   +--> f(2, 3, callbackFn2)
          callbackFn2(null, 2 + 3)
            if (!err) console.log(res)
              console.log(5)                     //~> 5
        end f
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference is the time at which `a` and `b` are evaluated. When you pass a closure to `setTimeout`, the variables are getting read when the closure that uses them is executed - after you had reassigned them. When you pass `a` and `b` to `callAsync`, they are evaluated as part of the call - immediately. The closure inside `callAsync` will only see the value `args = [2, 3, (…)=>{…}]`.

Comment: How can I make `callAsync` be really called async in that case?

Comment: It is really async, it executes asynchronously after `a` and `b` have been modified, but since it doesn't use that `a` or `b` and the copies of `a` and `b` that it does use haven't been modified, you see the original values being used.

Comment: @JohnZobolas `f` *is* called asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Your callAsync is completely async, but the values of `a` and `b` are copied at the time you call `callAsync`. It is equivalent to:

```
setTimeout((a,b) => 
f(a, b, (err, res) => {
    if (!err) console.log(res);
}), 0, a, b);
```

To achieve what you want you could use an object since they are reference types they are not copied when you pass them as arguments:

```js
// calls function f on next event loop
function callAsync(f, ...args) {
    setTimeout(() => f(...args), 0);
}

var f = (data, cb) => cb(null, data.a + data.b);

var data = {
  a: 2,
  b: 3,    
};

callAsync(f, data, (err, res) => {
    if (!err) console.log(res);
});

data.a = 10;
data.b = -10;
```